# data can't be updated in mongodb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

This error appears in my node js console:

> (node:6048) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: document must be a valid JavaScript object

```
router.post('/datapassfup', (req, res) => {
        console.log("submitted values are",req.body)
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var dbo = db.db("mohan");
            var myobj =req.body;
            dbo.collection("customers").updateOne({$set:{myobj}}, function(err, res) {
              if (err) throw err;
              //console.log("1 document inserted");
              db.close();
            });
          });
        res.json({
            statusCode: 200,
            result: "hi how are you!",
        })
    }
    );
```

Comment: data can't be update in mongodb database...Give any solution

Comment: What do you mean by data can't be update in mongo database? Are you checking the right table? Because the updated object returned by node.js is snapshot of new data on database side.

Answer (score 1):

updateOne() has first parameter as filter. Define your filter and then update.

```
//suppose you are getting id in order to update
    let userId = req.body.updatedUser.id;
    let userName = req.body.updatedUser.username;
    let name = req.body.updatedUser.name;
    dbo.collection("customers").updateOne({_id: userId},{$set:{name, username:userName}}, 
    function(err, res) {
                  if (err) throw err;
                  //console.log("1 document inserted");
                  db.close();
                });
              });
```

Comment: This type of code I can get an updated value in node js console but it does not update on mongodb. I could not find the reason. Please help me

Comment: Can you write the object that you are getting in req.body ? Furthermore, have you confirmed that you are connecting to DB?

Comment: updated values are { updatedUser: { id: 1, name: 'hello', username: 'Raja Gokul' } }--this is what am getting in node js

Comment: Yes its connected to DB

Comment: So you are getting all values inside "updatedUser" object. If this is what you are getting, i updated my answer accordingly. Just make sure about the id field.  _id in MongoDB stores in the form of hexadecimal. Since you are getting id as 1, so i don't think so you want to compare it with _id in MongoDB. apart from _id, do you have id field in MongoDB as well? if so replace _id with id.

Comment: dbo.collection("customers").updateOne({"_id":req.body.id},{$set:{myobj}}, function(err, res) { -- this line only problem to update mongo db data

Comment: how the schema of "customer" has written? And if you console log "req.body" are what are the results those are printing in console?

Comment: req.body console value is, { updatedUser: { id: 1, name: 'hello', username: 'mohanraja' } }

Comment: It should be same as for creating mongodb database according to our react crud input fields??

Comment: ok so these are the values coming from client side. Now how you designed the "customer" schema?

Comment: sir...I jus created db name as "mohan" and collection name is "customers" tats it.

Comment: If you are learning MERN Stack (CRUD Operation), check out this tutorial.  https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/the-mern-stack-tutorial-building-a-react-crud-application-from-start-to-finish-part-2-637f337e5d61

Answer (score 0):

I think you were not passing the condition that where you want the update like add     `name=mohan` .

> Use cors for cross origin request and body parser for parse the form
>   data

```
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cors());
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
//url like var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017"
     router.post('/datapassfup', (req, res) => {
                console.log("submitted values are",req.body)
                MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    var dbo = db.db("mohan");
                    var myobj =req.body;
                    dbo.collection("customers").updateOne({name:"mohan"},{$set:{myobj}}, function(err, res) {
                      if (err) throw err;
                      //console.log("1 document inserted");
                      db.close();
                    });
                  });
                res.json({
                    statusCode: 200,
                    result: "hi how are you!",
                })
            }
            );
```

Comment: This type of code I can get an updated value in node js console but it does not update on mongodb. I could not find the reason. Please help me

Comment: check the data is came  with request or not ?

Comment: Am fresher so I do not know exactly how to  do this so give me some examples crud application using React js with mongoDB and nodeJS

Comment: now i have add more details if this answer solve your problem make accept it as answer